# New 2013 Facebook timeline (left sidebar) not showing up the same for friends in same lists?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

With the new sidebar on the left of personal FB timelines, there are "sections" including "about" "friends" and "photos" on the top. Then you could add things like "music" "movies" "likes" and any other 3rd party apps like fitness apps or tumblr for example.

I have set my sections to be "music" "flickr" and "likes". I see that every time I go to my timeline. But when I "view as" a couple of friends, not everyone sees the three additional sections ("music" "flickr" and "likes"). Some of my friends see them, and some don't. But these two people seeing different things are in the same lists and have the same privacy levels.

I can't seem to find the link between the friends that can't see anything after the photos" section and those that do see the additional sections ("music" "flickr" and "likes").

I've tried hiding the section and re-show the sections, doesn't work. And I've tried setting my privacy to "music" "flickr" and "likes" to all friends but still no hope.

Could someone help me so that all my friends could see all six sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really anyway to know for sure why friend A sees the section and friend B does not. You may need to compare actual activity per post. For example my music section will always appear regardless of what future privacy setting I have placed because all previous stories were set to public.

[image: Previous stories set to public]

The same goes for the likes section

[image: Likes]

You can try setting the privacy to public and see if that changes anything. If it doesn't most likely

- it can be that Friend B doesn't have Timeline sections yet (i.e. they will not be able to see it in this format, so the Audience Timeline preview is giving incorrect results) **or**
- it's a bug and you should submit a report https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/297365590303574

(A sure way to know, would be to ask the friends themselves if they see it, don't trust the "view as" tool at face value)